# Similar functionality as Excel Rate() function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, excel, vectorwise

Is there any functionality which work in SQL Server Query similar to as EXCEL Financial RATE() Funtion.

Please suggest me any approach as how to receive the same result by SQL Server Query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL TVM or Annuity Functions PV,FV,NPER,RATE,PMT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638510/sql-tvm-or-annuity-functions-pv-fv-nper-rate-pmt)

Comment: Hi Alex,  I changed my Tag as i need suggestion for vectorwise database. where i am afraid While and scripting not supported. For SQL Server this is fine but i need suggestion for vectorwise database.

Comment: I don't understand. Your question is about SQL Server, it says so in the title! If you have another question to ask, then post a different question. BUT before you do, I suggest that you do a Google search first.